# Magento Templates - Can extensions be bundled with a theme?

Tags: magento

I have a real noob Magento question. I'm helping a friend change the template their store is using but they are worried about losing the functionality of some of their extensions such as ajaxsearch. They don't know if it's actually an extension or part of the template. I can't seem to figure out if some of the extensions are built into the theme or if they are completely separate extensions. Is there an easy way to tell?

To give an example the ajaxsearch JS file's path seems to in the template path e.g http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/templatename/js/ajaxsearch.js
and if I go to system > configuration I can see it listed in the sidebar under Templates-Master (which I think is a brand name). In this case is this an extension and is this how file paths work for extensions? The fact that skin is in the file path is throwing me off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast way:
Each Magento extension provided as archive (.tgz). Unpack it to some folder outside Magento and check have it next path or not:

unpacked_folder/skin/frontend/default/templatename/js/ajaxsearch.js

(another trick is look in the first lines of ajaxsearch.js file, authors often write extension or theme names in it).

Long way:

1. Find where is this file included on page. Search for 'ajaxsearch.js' in xml files placed in app/design/frontend/default/templatename/layout/
   if not found, try to search in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/  etc.
   For example you find it in somefile.xml
2. Try to find which extension include this file. For doing this search 'somefile.xml' in config.xml files in local and community pools:

   app/code/local/some/extension1/etc/config.xml

   app/code/local/some/extension2/etc/config.xml

   app/code/community/some/extensionN/etc/config.xml

   etc
3. If you found it in ...some/extensionX/etc/config.xml - this mean what ajaxsearch.js belongs to some_extensionX extension. If not found - it belongs to theme.

Comment: Thanks for that! I take it I'll need FTP access for most of those tips? I haven't got it yet but have requested it. There weren't any hints in the js file itself.

Comment: Yes, you can use FileZilla or other ftp client for searching directly on server.